Setting up UR3e with ROS2 Iron - missing xacro files?
I have what seems to be a working installation of ROS2 Iron, and I have installed the UR driver https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/tree/main/ur_robot_driver to work with it.  However, when I try to use the robot launchfile ros2 launch ur_robot_driver ur_control.launch.py ur_type:=ur3e robot_ip:= I get errors about missing xacro files: specifically
No such file or directory: /opt/ros/iron/share/ur_description/urdf/inc/ur_joint_control.xacro [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ros/iron/share/ur_description/urdf/inc/ur_joint_control.xacro'
when processing file: /home/<username>/ws_moveit/install/ur_robot_driver/share/ur_robot_driver/urdf/ur.ros2_control.xacro
included from: /home/<username>/ws_moveit/install/ur_robot_driver/share/ur_robot_driver/urdf/ur.urdf.xacro

/urdf/inc/ur_sensors.xacro is also not present in /opt/ros/iron/share/ur_description/urdf/inc/ and is called for inside ur.ros2_control.xacro
Is this a path issue and they are somewhere else, or are these files not included in the Iron ROS2 distribution and the UR driver needs to be updated?
Thanks!

I found the solution, which was that I was not using the ROS Iron branch of https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/tree/iron. When I changed branches and rebuilt, I got a new error.

Hi Kat, welcome to Robotics StackExchange. Would you mind putting your comment down as an answer and then accepting it? This would show that the question has been answered. :)

As ssarkar states, please post the solution as an answer, and not as a comment - that is not what the comment section is for.. Also, please take the [tour] to better understand how the Q&A mechanism of Stack Exchange operates.
